# Reducing a system to first order

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Convert the following to a first order system $$x''(t) = k_x(x(t) - y(t))^{-2}, \ \ y''(t) = k_y(x(t) - y(t))^{-2},$$ $$x'(0)=v_x, \ \ y'(0) = v_y, \ \ x(0) = x_0, \ \ y(0) = y_0.$$

I know how to reduce simpler systems, by using a substitution. However, I'm lost when all of these variables are involved.

Comment: wait so what's the problem? why can't you define x'=u and y'=w? Why does that not work? It wouldn't be a linear system sure, but since there would be no second derivatives of variables, it would still be first order.

Comment: @WilliamKrinsman 

Sure, then we'll obtain $u'(t) = \frac{k_x}{(x(t)-y(t))^2}$ and $w'(t) = \frac{k_y}{(x(t)-y(t))^2}$. Where do we go from here?

Comment: @Moo Yes, the question is written correctly.

Comment: That's a first order system isn't it? So it's been reduced to first order? I have the impression that your question is different from what you are actually asking

Comment: @Elliot : it's not written quite correctly : It is not specified if $k_x$ and $k_y$ are constant or function of $t$.